# Socket data does not appear to be getting through to client

Tags: java, sockets

I've written some serverside socket handling code and I'm concerned that potentially my packets are not always making it back to the client.  I am logging all my events and in my log files it says I am sending the information.  But the client is also logging events and in their logs they say they do not receive anything.

My code to send the data is as follows:

```
public void write(Packet packet) {
    String data = packet.serialize();
    log("Send=[" + data + "]", "Write"); // log to file

    try {
        _writer.write(data);
        _writer.flush();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log(ex, "write");
    }
}
```

Each socket is created on a new thread and I create my writers and readers immediately like so (in the public run method):

```
// _sockt is a Java Socket object
_writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(_socket
                    .getOutputStream()));
            _reader = new SocketReader(_socket);
```

SocketReader is just a wrapper class I created for listening for responses and has a public read method like so:

```
public String read() throws IOException, SocketTimeoutException {

    _socket.setSoTimeout(_timeOut);

    if(_reader == null)
        _reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_socket.getInputStream()));

            // read from the stream
    return new PacketDataInputStream(_reader).read();
}
```

The PacketDataInputStream wrapper class:

```
BufferedReader _reader = null;

public PacketDataInputStream(BufferedReader reader)
{
    _reader = reader;
}

public String read() throws IOException, SocketException {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int c = 0;

    while((c = _reader.read()) != -1)
    {
        char ch = (char)c;

        builder.append(ch);

        if(ch == PacketConstants.ETX)
            break;
    }

    if(builder.length() > 0)
        return builder.toString();
    else
        return null;

}
```

The way I'm creating the actual socket listener objects is pretty standard I think:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
        server = new ServerSocket( port, 0, address);

                    // My own manager class to handle all the sockets connected 
        WebSocketManager manager = new WebSocketManager(this);

        Socket connection = null;

        while(bContinue)
        {
            connection = server.accept();

            if(bContinue) {
                                    // assign the socket to a new thread and start
                                    // that thread
                manager.newSocket(connection);  
            } else {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
```

- Is is possible that I'm using the wrong objects for sending the data back.
- Should I even be using a bufferedwriter and reader?  I had thought that these were the best way to go but now I'm not so sure.

It's important to note that this does not happen all the time, just sporadically.  It could be the clients code having bugs but I need to make sure that I'm doing it correctly before going back to them.

This code is run on a *Linux Ubuntu* server.  Logging occurs to a text file, nothing special there.  My log files show the **Send=""** data going back to the client and no exception so it appears as if the .write and .flush() worked?  Socket connections are persistant and only closed by the client and or network issues.

**UPDATE ----- Client Side code -------:**

I did manage to get some of the client side code for how they are handling the send and receiving of data (just in case it's more obvious on their end).  The client is actually connecting to this server via an **Android device** (if that helps).

Creation of socket

```
static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 20000;       // Maximum packet size

java.net.InetAddress server = java.net.InetAddress.getByName(url);
socket = new Socket(server, port);
// Set socket options:
socket.setReceiveBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
socket.setSendBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

Sending:

```
try {
            // Send the packet:
        OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
        stream.write(p.getByteArray ());
        stream.flush();

            // Update the time:
        lastPacketSendTime = new Date ();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        setError("Error sending packet (" + e.getMessage() + ")", ERROR_IO);
        return false;
    }
```

Receiving:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);
            // Get the reader:
        inputStream = socket.getInputStream();



     while (true) {
                    // Get the next character:
                int value = inputStream.read();
                    // Check for -1, indicating that the socket is closed:
                if (value == -1) {
                        // The socket is closed remotely, so close it locally as well:
                    disconnect();
                    inputStream = null;
                    return null;
                }
                                // ... and a bunch of other stuff to handle the actual data

                        }
```

**EDIT 14-Nov:**
This is actually proving to be more of a problem now.  Both the client logs and the server logs appear to be sending.  But at times the data doesn't appear to come through or if it does it is sometimes coming through 10 - 30 - 60 second delayed.

I can provide more information if required.

Comment: Can you show `PacketDataInputStream.read()`?

Comment: @Attila Added the .read() method to the question

Comment: What is the value of `PacketConstants.ETX`?  Are you sure it is appended to the end of the serialized packet string -- does it show up at the end of the logged data string?

Comment: @Attila  Yes, I'm sure the data is being sent in correct format out as my log files show the correct data being sent.  Just the client at the other end never seems to get it, although that's whay their logs say.  I was just a bit concerned that my usage of Buffered readers, writers etc???

Comment: Can you show the `PacketDataInputStream` Constructor? At least the `PacketDataInputStream(BufferedReader reader)` constructor. And no exceptions being thrown by client? No messages? And you never answered, what is the value of `PacketConstants.ETX`?

Comment: Is the socket TCP or UDP? Or a different transport protocol?

Comment: @Austin - Added constructor.  It's pretty simple.  He reckons he just doesn't get the messages I send.  I seem to answer his as my log file says I am, but he reckons nothing gets through.  I was wondering if it's possible the objects I'm using for sending (Buffer) are doing something???

Comment: PacketConstants.ETX = *.  My log file shows that this is presant on the packet when sent.

Answer (score 1):

When you use BufferedReaders and BufferedWriters things get buffered.  How about using the input and output streams directly..  Also, writers are character based, I don't know if you need to send binary data but if so that will be a problem with writers.

Comment: I had hoped that the Buffered way of doing things was the more accepted practice.  Perhaps I need to go away from this incase there are bugs?  I do call a flush on on my writer in the hopes this would cause the buffer to free up?

Comment: flush should make sure it sends the data over but if your reader won't be affected, it's still buffered and probably waiting to receive a return character before it will stop blocking.

Comment: cheers.  I've trawled my code and it's rare that I would be having the receive open at the same time as writing, however it's my understanding they don't block each other anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this will be to your any use or not.. but i am giving you the code i used for client server communication..

**Client Side:**

```
public class ClientWala {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Boolean b = true;
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);

    System.out.println("connected: "+s.isConnected());


    OutputStream output = s.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(output,true);

    // to write data to server
    while(b){

        if (!b){

             System.exit(0);
        }

        else {
            pw.write(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        }
    }


    // to read data from server
    InputStream input   = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String data = null;

    while ((data = br.readLine())!=null){

        // Print it using sysout, or do whatever you want with the incoming data from server

    }




    }
}
```

**Server Code:**

```
import java.io.*
import java.net.*;


public class ServerTest {

    ServerSocket s;

    public void go() {

        try {
            s = new ServerSocket(44457);

            while (true) {

                Socket incoming = s.accept();
                Thread t = new Thread(new MyCon(incoming));
                t.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    class MyCon implements Runnable {

        Socket incoming;

        public MyCon(Socket incoming) {

            this.incoming = incoming;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(incoming.getOutputStream(),
                        true);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                        incoming.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String inp = null;

                boolean isDone = true;

                System.out.println("TYPE : BYE");
                System.out.println();
                while (isDone && ((inp = br.readLine()) != null)) {

                    System.out.println(inp);
                    if (inp.trim().equals("BYE")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("THANKS FOR CONNECTING...Bye for now");
                        isDone = false;
                        s.close();
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ServerTest().go();

    }

}
```

Comment: while (){ if (!b) ... } doesn't make any sense whatsoever.